# Polymer dom-if doesn't restamp computed condition under dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer

So I have a scenario:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{objects}}" as="o" filter="{{_filter(filter)}}">
  ...
  <template is="dom-if" if="_isHidden" restamp>
    foo
  </template>
  ...
</template>
```

Now, the `_filter` function forces rerendering items under the `dom-repeat` every time my `filter` property changes (since it's observed by `_filter`. This is not the problem as it works properly, but the catch is that the `_hidden` function might return true or false based on another property (which could also change), and whenever the filter rerenders I need to force re-evaluation of `_isHidden` hence hide or show the contents of the `dom-if` template.

Anyone has an idea what could be my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post relavant javascript also

Comment: It's not very relevant at this point, `_isHidden()` might return true or false and `_filter(filter)` returns `function(object)` which returns true or false which is in charge of whether or not the iteration will be rendered or not.

Comment: If your `dom-repeat` is getting re-evaluated then `dom-if` by default is getting re-evaluated

Comment: why are you using filter and dom-if to evaluate whether something gets hidden?

Comment: you need to add the variable that isHidden depends on as an argument
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isHidden(dependency)}}" restamp>

Comment: Think a grid/table. `_isHidden` checks for columns visibility and `_filter` checks row visibility. Suggestions for this use case (for optimal performance in mind) also welcome...

Answer (score 1):

You have to also bind the `_isHidden` property:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{objects}}" as="o" filter="{{_filter(filter)}}">
  ...
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isHidden}}" restamp>
    foo
  </template>
  ...
</template>
```